# How do I create a Virtual Name Host on Apache2 for a service running on localhost:8080

Tags: virtualhost, apache2, localhost

i have a server with apache that runs a mailing service, a wordpress multisite

I have followed guides online to make the above work

now I have a service from Vaadin (java stuff) running on localhost:8080. I can also access this through my public ip:8080.

How do I go about making a "pretty link" for the localhost:8080 service.

Could be example.com/something or something.example.com (any type of readable link is what I am after).

I tried adding the following to 000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ProxyPass /jenkins/ myip:8080
ProxyPassReverse /jenkins/ myip:8080
SetOutputFilter proxy-html
ProxyHTMLURLMap myip:8080 mywebsite.com/jenkins
ProxyHTMLExtended On 
</VirtualHost>
```

I added this below my other virtualhost *:80.

Comment: I tried to follow the guide by adding <VirtualHost *:80>
        ProxyPass               /jenkins/ http://myip:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse        /jenkins/ http://myip:8080/
        SetOutputFilter proxy-html
        ProxyHTMLURLMap http://myip:8080/ https://mywebsite.com/jenkins/
        ProxyHTMLExtended On       # by default only HTML output is filtered
</VirtualHost>
But it did not change anything. I tried both going to myip:8080 and mywebsite.com/jenkins. Nothing new there.

Comment: myip is localhost or 127.0.0.1, did you done this? and nevertheless post related information in an commentary. edit and update the question instead...

Comment: Better don't change the URI path with reverse proxy; if the origin was on `localhost:8080/jenkins/`, better make it accessible as `public:80/jenkins/`. **Don't** export `localhost:8080/` as `public:80/jenkins/` or `localhost:8080/jenkins/` as `public:80/`. Avoid `ProxyHTMLURLMap`. There are certain problems associated with that, like that paths can also be put into CSS and into JavaScript code and even built dynamically within JavaScript and there is no "ProxyHTMLURLMap"-like function that is able to remap them all.